# Problem with alternate coloring

Tags: php

I am having problem with coloring alternate table rows.

```
print '<tr '.if(childnum%2==0){.'bgcolor="#CCFFCC">'.} else {.'bgcolor="#990000">'};
```

This results in the following error: "`Syntax Error, unexpected T_IF in /home/ on line [...]`"

Comment: Sybtax Error, unexpected T_IF in /home/ on line this.

Whats need to reduce my reputation?

Comment: Your question was no question. You got downvoted because you were missing cruicial information.

Comment: @Aditii It seems you have more code just than the above. The best is for you to reconstruct your question

Answer (score 4):

```
print '<tr '.(($childnum % 2 == 0) ? 'bgcolor="#CCFFCC">' : 'bgcolor="#990000">');
```

is better

probably `childnum%2` should be `$childnum % 2`

Comment: <?php while($childdetail=mysql_fetch_assoc($child)) {
  print '<tr '.(($childnum/2!=0) ? 'bgcolor="#CCFFCC">' : 'bgcolor="#990000">') };

Answer (score 1):

do not write the code in that manner, in few weeks you won't understand it no more, TRUST ME

```
if($childnum%2==0){
    $mybgcolor = '#CCFFCC';
} else {
    $mybgcolor = '#990000';
}
print '<tr bgcolor="'.$mybgcolor.'">';
```

much simpler and readable

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if/else` logic to set a string variable to the background color you want before issuing the print statement.  Then, just include that variable as the `bgcolor` value when you print.

Comment: No you don't.  Martin's solution is exactly what I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($childnum % 2 == 0) {
     $color = '#CCFFCC';
} else {
     $color = '#990000';
}

print '<tr bgcolor="'.$color.'">';
```

Do not mix conditional statements (like `if`) and language constructs (like `print`) or functions.

And keep readability in mind. Remember: There will come a time when you have to maintain that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$tr = '';

if(($childnum % 2) == 0) $tr = '<tr bgcolor="#CCFFCC">';
else $tr = '<tr bgcolor="#990000">';

print $tr;
```

What I usualy do to solve a problem is:

- Break the code up into different segments
- Make it work as I want
- Refactor it